# Get filter value so text can automatically change

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I get the value of the filter so I can use it as a condition for a text?

As: If Filter TYPE is GASS EQUIPMENT then write "FOR GASS EQUIPMENT"

For example. In the image bellow I have a simple table which is filtered by TYPE = "Gass Equipment".
How do I get the value, in this "Gass Equipment", so I can dynamically change the text of the title every time I put a new filter?

[image]

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239)

Comment: The data is not important, but I can for sure share the sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-6nM637gHL2EzKA2w-8AXXXK6ULwQtw/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=118230889496556766723&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show which rows/columns your data is in, so I will assume the table is in `A7:C19`

Use the following formula:

```
="FOR " & INDEX(A2:A10,MATCH(SUBTOTAL(5,B2:B10),B2:B10))
```

Brief explanation:
`SUBTOTAL(5,)` will look for the Minimum visible value in column B
`MATCH` will return the row of that value
`INDEX` will return the value in column A for that row

For text only when you have one value filtered use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A10,INDEX(A2:A10,MATCH(SUBTOTAL(5,B2:B10),B2:B10)))=SUBTOTAL(3,B2:B10),"for " & INDEX(A2:A10,MATCH(SUBTOTAL(5,B2:B10),B2:B10)),IF(SUBTOTAL(3,B2:B10)=COUNTA(B2:B10),"for " & INDEX(A2:A10,MATCH(SUBTOTAL(5,B2:B10),B2:B10)),""))
```

Comment: It kinda worked. The only problem is that when there's no filter on the formula still brings a value. How can it be blank if there's no filter on?

Comment: See edit to my answer

Comment: It worked, but in my case it wasn't needed the second IF. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
="For "&INDEX(A6:A13,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A6,ROW(A6:A13)-ROW(A6),0)),ROW(A6:A13)-ROW(A6)+1)))
```

[image]